# LEFT JOIN a single row and filling in NULL values with the single row's value

Tags: sql-server

I have:

First Order with an item from the clothing category:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
        od.SalesOrderNumber,
        a.OrderDate,
        od.hasClothing
    FROM History a
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
        ON a.SalesOrderNumber=od.SalesOrderNumber
    WHERE od.hasClothing = 1
    ORDER BY a.OrderDate ASC 

+------------------+------------+-------------+
| SalesOrderNumber | KeyDate    | hasClothing |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
| SO57673          | 2007-11-09 |           1 |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
```

and ...

Another query that produces:

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| SalesOrderNumber | CustomerAltKey | OrderDate  |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| SO44063          | AW00011240     | 2005-08-30 |
| SO51205          | AW00011240     | 2007-07-03 |
| SO57673          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-09 |
| SO57953          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-14 |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to JOIN the two tables and produce:

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
| SalesOrderNumber | CustomerAltKey | OrderDate  | OrderDate >= KeyDate |
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
| SO44063          | AW00011240     | 2005-08-30 |                    0 |
| SO51205          | AW00011240     | 2007-07-03 |                    0 |
| SO57673          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-09 |                    1 |
| SO57953          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-14 |                    1 |
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
```

I've tried a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on SalesOrderNumber, OrderDate, etc. and tried to COALESCE null values into the `2007-11-09` date ... but everything I've tried has failed.  I just get:

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
| SalesOrderNumber | CustomerAltKey | OrderDate  | OrderDate >= KeyDate |
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
| SO44063          | AW00011240     | 2005-08-30 | NULL                 |
| SO51205          | AW00011240     | 2007-07-03 | NULL                 |
| SO57673          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-09 | 1                    |
| SO57953          | AW00011240     | 2007-11-14 | NULL                 |
+------------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+
```

Any suggestions?  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Add the structure of the involved tables on your question. That would help us to help you.

Comment: Add at least the candidate keys and columns of ALL tables in use. That is fundamental information about the tables that is absolutely required to understand the data.

Comment: So you're basically ignoring the SalesOrderNumber in your JOIN, that's what the desired output shows?

Answer (score 0):

As you need to get the field in your query result you need to use CASE statement.

If you post the definition of the tables we can help you. Meanwhile the solution should be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
    od.SalesOrderNumber,
    a.OrderDate,
    od.hasClothing,
    CASE WHEN a.OrderDate >= od.KeyDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RESULT_FIELD_NAME
FROM History a
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
    ON a.SalesOrderNumber=od.SalesOrderNumber
WHERE od.hasClothing = 1
ORDER BY a.OrderDate ASC
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data I created this. However from the sample data it looks like you don't care about joining on `SalesOrderNumber`. Therefore I `CROSS JOIN`ed the sets to procude the expected output.

```
SELECT 
    r.SalesOrderNumber,r.CustomerAltKey,r.OrderDate,
    [OrderDate>=KeyDate]=CAST(CASE WHEN l.KeyDate<=r.OrderDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM
    (
        SELECT SalesOrderNumber='SO57673',KeyDate='20071109',hasClothing=1
    ) AS l
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SalesOrderNumber='SO44063',CustomerAltKey='AW00011240',OrderDate='20050830' UNION ALL
        SELECT SalesOrderNumber='SO51205',CustomerAltKey='AW00011240',OrderDate='20070703' UNION ALL
        SELECT SalesOrderNumber='SO57673',CustomerAltKey='AW00011240',OrderDate='20071109' UNION ALL
        SELECT SalesOrderNumber='SO57953',CustomerAltKey='AW00011240',OrderDate='20071114' 
    ) AS r
```

Result:

```
+------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| SalesOrderNumber | CustomerAltKey | OrderDate | OrderDate>=KeyDate |
+------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| SO44063          | AW00011240     |  20050830 |                  0 |
| SO51205          | AW00011240     |  20070703 |                  0 |
| SO57673          | AW00011240     |  20071109 |                  1 |
| SO57953          | AW00011240     |  20071114 |                  1 |
+------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
```